# Using std::bind in a switch on type situation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates

I have a situation where I need to do some switching on some input flag and I want to either do a binary comparison or a unary operation on some input function object.  So for example

```
template <typename Func>
void do_something(Object one, Object possibly_not_here, Func function) {
    switch(flag) {
        case 1:
            call_function_with_one_argument(one.arg);
        case 2:
            call_function_with_two_arguments(one.some_other_member, possibly_not_here.some_other_member);
    }
}
```

I am planning on passing a lambda to this function which will either accept two arguments or just one argument.  The `possibly_not_here` parameter may not be passed to this function.  This will work because the function object that I pass in will be templated so it will be able to handle different types.

Is there a way I can achieve this efficiently with `std::bind()` or variadic templates?  I cannot think of a way to do this that would not duplicate code...

Comment: Can't you default `possibly_not_here` to something?

Comment: That is the problem! That would emit a warning

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you could show an "inefficient" or repetitive implementation and ask how it could be improved?

Answer (score 4):

```
template<typename Func>
void do_something(Object one, Func &&f){
    f(one);
}

template<typename Func>
void do_something(Object one, Object two, Func &&f){
    f(one, two);
}
```

And in your example I can't understand why you pass `Func` at all.

[Here's it in action.](https://goo.gl/f3an3h)

Comment: Do you need to use forwarding for parameters here?

Comment: @MtRoad Well, in his example he's passing copies of a concrete type. But if the arguments were template types, yeah you'd want to.

Answer (score 0):

Given the presence of the `flag` and the `switch` based on the `flag`, you are mixing the runtime constraints of determining the appropriate function with the compile time constraint of knowing whether or not there are one or two arguments for the function.

To satisfy the runtime variability, you may need to investigate the use of the a [variadic function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) (i.e. `call_me(Flag flag, Func function, Object one...)`), but I'm sure that is not what you want.

For the compile time determination, you could simply use [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke);

```
std::invoke(func, one);
std::invoke(func, one, two);
```

These calls are tantamount to;

```
std::forward<Func>(f)(std::forward<Object>(one)/*, std::forward<Object>(two)*/)
```

---

A basic/suitable implementation for the `invoke` (if not available on your platform) is;

```
template< class F, class... Args>
auto invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
  return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```